# Binning of multiple files with uneven intervals in R

Tags: r, intervals, bin

I have many files with unequal number of rows.

The data looks like this for one file:

```
Height Temp
1014.0 22.4
992.0 23
850.0 15.2
557.0 -6.1
407.0 -17.1
314.0 -29.5
200 -51.9
```

I want to take the average of the values if it is within the following intervals.

```
1000-925
925-850
850-700
700-600
600-500
500-400
400-300
300-200
200-100
100-0
```

I have to do this for multiple files with also different height values.

Any suggestions on how to do this in R correctly?
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your heights with `cut` and then summarise by group:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, category = cut(Height, c(seq(0, 700, 100), 850, 925, 1000, Inf))) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(average_height = mean(Height, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  category    average_height
  <fct>                <dbl>
1 (100,200]              200
2 (300,400]              314
3 (400,500]              407
4 (500,600]              557
5 (700,850]              850
6 (925,1e+03]            992
7 (1e+03,Inf]           1014
```

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to use `sqldf`, with a calendar table join and aggregation approach:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "SELECT c.min_temp, c.max_temp, AVG(t.Temp) AS temp_avg
        FROM temps c
        LEFT JOIN df t ON t.Temp > c.min_temp AND t.Temp <= c.max_temp
        GROUP BY c.min_temp, c.max_temp"
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

**Data:**

```
# this data frame stores the temperature ranges for the averages
temps <- data.frame(min_temp=c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 850, 925),
                    max_temp=c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 850, 925, 1000))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will have to check this library first. :v:

Answer (score 1):

An alternative in base R using `findInterval` to create groups and `aggregate` to take `mean` by group.

```
df$group <- findInterval(df$Height, c(seq(0, 700, 100), 850, 925, 1000))
aggregate(Height~group, df, mean)
```